# Drop-down list in properties window to start at certain index

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, editor

**Background information:**
We have a UserControl called Sensor.
Sensor has a property called SlaveSensor.
The type of the property SlaveSensor is Sensor.

```
public Sensor SlaveSensor;
{
    get
    {
        return _slaveSensor;
    }
    set
    {
        //Some more code for checking various stuff...

        _slaveSensor; = value;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the type of the property is the same as the UserControl itself.
The property SlaveSensor is normally set via the properties window during design time.
Visual Studio automatically provides the editor as a drop-down list, from which one can select from all available Sensors on the form.

**My question is:**
How can I make the drop-down list start at a specified instance in the list,
to make it quicker to find the right Sensor to set for the property?

The name of the Sensor to set as the property is always nearly the same as the name of the Sensor for which the property is being set.
So if e.g. the drop-down list would simply auto scroll to the index in the list that has the name of the Sensor for which the property is being set,
I have achieved my goal.

**What do I have so far:**
I assume that I need to implement a custom property editor.
I might actually be able to create one with a drop-down list, and fill this with strings,
but the existing is OK as it is, I just need to tell it to drop-down to a certain index when clicked.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this.

```
string text = "SomeText";
var item = dropdown.Items.FindByText(text);
if(item!= null)
   item.Selected = true;
```

Or by value:

```
string value = "SomeValue";
var item = dropdown.Items.FindByValue(value);
if (item != null)
  item.Selected = true;
```

Taken from top answer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1176550/How-to-set-selected-value-to-dropdown-by-selected)